# how to create a Dataset of [(Row, Row)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a function that takes in a `Dataset[(Row, Row)]` and im trying to test this function but im not sure how i can create a Dataset that would be of `Dataset[(Row, Row)]`

I've tried the following but it says that this is of type `tuple2[DataFrame, DataFrame]`

```
      val df: Dataset[(Row,Row)] = (
        Seq(
          ("NOW", "active", 1, 11),
          ("BEFORE", "active", 2, 11),
          ("AFTER", "active", 3, 33)
        ).toDF(),
        Seq(
          ("NOW", "sub_uuid1", 1, "com_uuid1"),
          ("BEFORE", "sub_uuid2", 2, "com_uuid2"),
          (null, null, 3, null)
        ).toDF()
      )
```

how can I write the above so it would be of type `Dataset[(Row,Row)]`

Comment: What does this function do? Is it possible for you to share its source code? It seems weird to me to use such a structure as `Row` is meant to represent an entire row in the dataset.

Comment: @jrook It's not strange at all. `Row` represents a `StructType`, which can be either a struct column or a row.

Answer (score -1):

because you created tuple of `Dataset[Row]`:

```
val ds1: Dataset[Row] = Seq(
          ("NOW", "active", 1, 11),
          ("BEFORE", "active", 2, 11),
          ("AFTER", "active", 3, 33)
        ).toDF()
val ds2: Dataset[Row] = Seq(
          ("NOW", "sub_uuid1", 1, "com_uuid1"),
          ("BEFORE", "sub_uuid2", 2, "com_uuid2"),
          (null, null, 3, null)
        ).toDF()
```

and you just made tuple of them:

```
val df: (Dataset[Row], Dataset[Row]) = (ds1, ds2)
```

you can do that you need so:

```
val df: Dataset[(Row, Row)] =
  Seq(
    (Row("NOW", "active", 1, 11), Row("NOW", "sub_uuid1", 1, "com_uuid1")),
    (Row("BEFORE", "active", 2, 11), Row("BEFORE", "sub_uuid2", 2, "com_uuid2")),
    (Row("AFTER", "active", 3, 33), Row(null, null, 3, null))
  ).toDS()
```

actually it's a bad practice to create Dataset with tupled rows. If you can rewrite your function to take two Dataframes (`DataFrame: a, DataFrame: b`) instead `ab: Dataset[(Row, Row)]` it would be much better.